# Which permissions are needed to export blobs

Tags: sql-server, blob

I import binary data into SQL Server 2012 Express. This works.

But I can't export it into a file on harddisk.
I suppose very much that it is a incorrect or missing permission on the SQL server for the user who tries to export.

I backuped the database with blob data copied it on another machine and the script worked as expected. On this dev machine there is no domain user, no certain user logged in.

So my question is: Which roles, permission, etc. are neccessary to export blobs??

On the not working machine I get no error at all, it seems like everything worked but no files have been created. Folder structure would allow to create files.

I found similar problems of other users in the web, they also asked for certain permissions, but did not get any reply.

Script used

```
   DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY (max);
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @Obj INT


   SET NOCOUNT ON

  SELECT @ImageData = (SELECT PictureData FROM [dbo].[ScanIT_tblProjektbilder] WHERE ID= @PicID);

   SET @Path2OutFile = 'C:\Users\michael\Desktop\test.jpg' -- CONCAT(@ImageFolderPath ,'\', @Filename );


BEGIN TRY
 EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@Obj OUTPUT;
 EXEC sp_OASetProperty @Obj ,'Type',1;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Open';
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'SaveToFile', NULL, @Path2OutFile, 2;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Close';
 EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
 END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll potentially need to allow to run OA stored procedures on server (and then turn it off, when you're done):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that before that, 'OLE Automation Procedures' was reconfigured of course.

Answer (score 0):

For the code posted in order to use all the `sp_OA*` procedures the membership in the **sysadmin** fixed server role or `execute` permission directly on every `sp_OA*` is required. You can find it here [sp_OACreate (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: it seems that SQL-server cannot export and write to any folder of C:

I tried on 3 machines, everywhere the same issue.
When I export to any other local drive it works, but not on C:

Now, I try to find out how to enable write permissions for a certain user on C:.

I suppose that this user must be the user which is logged on to the SQL-server.